# remove powered number from string in python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I want to remove the power of number from string. how can I do that?
for example the number is:

```
1¹
```

I know its Unicode is :1\u2071

I find this:

```
 text = re.sub("(\([^)]*\)|\w)\^(\([^)]*\)|\w)", ' ', text)
```

but not works.

Comment: import re
test = '1¹'
text_n = re.sub("(¹)", ' ', test)
text_n

Comment: https://rextester.com/NHXV37698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have found seems to match expressions like x^y, where the superscript is expressed with the `^` character.

However, the strings you are trying to match uses actual superscript characters, which are limited to these:

```
²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ
```

Therefore, you could just create a character class with those:

```
\d+[²³¹⁰ⁱ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ]+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KBh0Qe/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
test = '1¹'
text_n = re.sub("(¹)", ' ', test)
print (text_n)
```

https://rextester.com/NHXV37698

Answer (score 0):

Unicode `1\u2071` will match `1ⁱ`

To match 1 or more digits followed by for example superscript `0`, `i`, `1-9` `+`, `-`, `=`, `(`, `)`, `n` you could use a character class.

```
[0-9][\u2070\u2071\u00b9\u00b2\u00b3\u2074-\u207F]
       ⁰     ⁱ     ¹     ²     ³     ⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾ⁿ
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqKqPD/1) | [Unicode.org pdf](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf)